# Hibernate Schema Export failure without error

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, java-ee-7, wildfly-9

Since monday the error occurs, that the data schema is no longer exported correctly. The database tables are not created, even though there are no errors visible in the console log. This error also occures in earlier versions that ran perfectly fine before monday. Also newly created projects with maven have the same problem.
Furthermore, I installed the local WildFly server anew and also tried older versions (WildFly 8.x and 9.x). 
The database in use is a mySQL database, but I also tried with other database types like H2 without any success.

The persistence.xml is as follows:

```
<persistence-unit name="primary">
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/chargingTransactionWarehouse</jta-data-source>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The console output:

```
19:09:30,499 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.4.3.Final
19:09:30,705 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
19:09:30,781 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) starting
19:09:31,946 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'job-repository-type' in the resource at address '/subsystem=batch' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
19:09:31,954 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 7) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
19:09:31,968 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 7) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=java:jboss/datasources/chargingTransactionWarehouse' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
19:09:31,969 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 7) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=java:jboss/datasources/ChargingTransactionWarehouse' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
19:09:31,972 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 7) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'enabled' in the resource at address '/subsystem=datasources/data-source=CrowdStrom' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
19:09:31,992 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found chargingTransactionWarehouse.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called chargingTransactionWarehouse.war.dodeploy
19:09:32,026 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
19:09:32,064 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
19:09:32,073 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
19:09:32,127 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
19:09:32,143 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
19:09:32,146 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
19:09:32,149 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
19:09:32,151 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
19:09:32,152 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
19:09:32,161 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.2.Final
19:09:32,186 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
19:09:32,215 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.2.5.Final)
19:09:32,253 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
19:09:32,265 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
19:09:32,267 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
19:09:32,275 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
19:09:32,274 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
19:09:32,294 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.9.Final starting
19:09:32,748 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path C:\Users\crowdstrom\wildfly-9.0.2.Final/welcome-content
19:09:32,758 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
19:09:32,784 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
19:09:32,835 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
19:09:32,989 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
19:09:33,102 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
19:09:33,192 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar" (runtime-name: "mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar")
19:09:33,192 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "chargingTransactionWarehouse.war" (runtime-name: "chargingTransactionWarehouse.war")
19:09:33,244 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\crowdstrom\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone\deployments
19:09:33,431 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 5.0.0.Final
19:09:33,617 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
19:09:33,619 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
19:09:33,640 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for primary
19:09:33,642 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar_com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver_5_1
19:09:33,647 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
19:09:33,660 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ChargingTransactionWarehouse]
19:09:33,661 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/CrowdStrom]
19:09:33,661 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/chargingTransactionWarehouse]
19:09:33,699 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'chargingTransactionWarehouse.war#primary'
19:09:33,722 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: primary
...]
19:09:33,725 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment chargingTransactionWarehouse.war
19:09:33,787 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
19:09:33,790 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
19:09:33,792 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
19:09:33,809 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
19:09:34,043 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0006: Starting Services for CDI deployment: chargingTransactionWarehouse.war
19:09:34,081 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-000900: 2.2.16 (SP1)
19:09:34,105 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0009: Starting weld service for deployment chargingTransactionWarehouse.war
19:09:34,531 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'chargingTransactionWarehouse.war#primary'
19:09:34,599 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
19:09:34,946 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
19:09:34,983 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
19:09:35,097 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
19:09:35,103 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000230: Schema export complete
19:09:35,812 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) Mojarra 2.2.12-jbossorg-2 20150729-1131 für Kontext '/chargingTransactionWarehouse' wird initialisiert.
19:09:36,351 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /chargingTransactionWarehouse
19:09:36,408 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar" (runtime-name : "mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar")
19:09:36,408 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "chargingTransactionWarehouse.war" (runtime-name : "chargingTransactionWarehouse.war")
19:09:36,835 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
19:09:36,836 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
19:09:36,836 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.2.Final) started in 6618ms - Started 350 of 536 services (229 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

I would be grateful for any helpful answer

King regards

EDIT:
I also tried to use the `<class>` tags as well as trying different mySQL dialects.

Comment: looks like a class scanner issue.  try puttin <class>com.yourclass</class> into your persistence.xml

Comment: Have already done it, doesn´t work

Answer (score 0):

Found the error! 
Due to the new JVM version, the actual error was not posted and the server was started. By installing the previous JVM version, the server failed to start and the `chargingTransactionWarehouse.war.failure` showed that there was a mapping error...